# "Remove everything and reinstall Windows" option; will it keep preinstalled software?

Tags: windows-8, reset

Windows 8 offers the option to "Remove everything and reinstall Windows" (see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc). Most of the notebooks you can buy come with some preinstalled software (e.g. bluray player, support tools,...). Will using the "Remove everything and reinstall Windows" option reinstall Windows including these preinstalled software or not?

Comment: No;  It will remove everything and reinstall Windows.  This means your personal files, install applications, and application settings will be lost.  The `Reset` image is a baseline from Microsoft not from your OEM, I can be update, if you had done it yourself.

Comment: So, I really would need the original image?

Comment: The original image resides on the disk already its a .wim image.

Comment: So that .wim image should include all preinstalled software of the manufacturer? Where is it located?

Comment: It does not contain the original software install by the manufacture.  Its location is well documented.  How you build a new image to replace it is also well documented.

Comment: Ok. So the original image from the manufacture is not stored anywhere?

Comment: That is up to the OEM to provide.